# Webflux How to subscribe only when client connection is fully established

Tags: java, postman, spring-webflux, server-sent-events

I have a ms that a client can connect to to recieve incoming notifications. When the client first connects a call to the db is made to retrieve all stored notifications.

**The problem:**
When I connect, even though there are 3 notifications in the db the client only recieves 1. Except on the first connect of the system, that for some reason returns the 3 notifications. That reason I assume is because when the system starts up for the first time the result of the SELECT statement from the database is not yet cached so it takes longer to get that data.

**My thinking of why this is happening:**
I believe this is happening because the data that comes from the db is being subscribed to the Flux before client connection is fully established, and so it only catches the last notification.

**My solution:**
I used the method `delaySubscription()` to delay subscription of the data and it works. However I dont feel very "safe" using it this way because if for some reason the connection takes longer the notifications will not be recieved. It is a even bigger problem because I intend to delete the notifications when they are sent.

**Question:**
Is there a way to check if connection is fully established before subscribing to the flux's?

**Another solution that might work:**
Maybe I could after establishing the connection in the client have another call to the ms that requests the initial notifications to be subscribed to the flux. However I believe this will not work in a distributed system, has the call can go to a container that the client is not subscribed to hence no notification will be sent.

**Question2:**
Am I overthinking this, and should I just have a diferent method for getting the initial notifications that just returns normal objects instead of a flux and then do the subscription?

Here is a bit of my code:

```
return Flux.merge(
         findAndCreateInitialNotifications(mainId).delaySubscription(Duration.ofSeconds(DURATION_OF_TIME_BEFORE_FIRST_NOTIFICATION)),
         data.filter(notification -> mainId.equals(((NotificationDto) notification.data()).getUserToSendNotificationTo()))
                             .switchIfEmpty(Flux.empty()).delaySubscription(Duration.ofSeconds(DURATION_OF_TIME_BEFORE_FIRST_NOTIFICATION)),
         heartBeat).onBackpressureBuffer();
```